# jQuery val() opens keyboard

Tags: jquery, iphone, forms, keyboard

I am using jqTouch for my web app which is running on a number of different phones, including the iPhone. The issue I have is with the iPhone only.

When I set a value on the form using the jQuery function `val()`, the keyboard opens up automatically. I don't want that to happen when I am changing the value or just adding a default value to a pre-exisiting form - it should only happen when the user tries to type in a value.

Is there a way to block the keyboard from popping up when `val()` is called on a form input? I tried to use `$(':focus').blur()` right after the call to `val()`, but the keyboard still opens and closes very fast, which isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that works, you could always use [jQuery aop](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/) to add a `$(':focus').blur()` to val calls. Something like this might work.

```
jQuery.aop.after( {target: jQuery, method: 'val'}, 
    function(response){
       if(typeof(response) == 'string')
         $(':focus').blur();

       return response;
});
```

I'm not quite sure that that target would work, but you could play around with this sort of thing and see if you can't get it working. If you didn't want to go adding side-effects to jQuery methods (probably a terrible idea), you could always craft your own function called `valNoKeyboard()`, either as a standalone function or jQuery plugin. I think the jQuery plugin route makes more sense, unless there's a better way to do this.

Comment: I will play with it and let you know if it works for me. Thanks.

Comment: It is working for me with small changes. Thanks again for the tip.

jQuery.aop.after( {target: jQuery, method: 'val'},
  function(response) {
    if(typeof(response) == 'string')
      $(':focus').blur()
    return response;
  }
);

Comment: Glad you got it working :). I'lle dit my answer to reflect what worked for you.